# Can I retrieve data from a table in laravel with multiple array conditions?

Tags: php, laravel, phpmyadmin

I am trying to dynamic populate the report based the values select in dropdown. 
For the same, I need to retrieve one or more columns from table using laravel 5.2. I am getting error "Trying to get property of non-object"

```
class ReportController extends Controller
{

public function index()
{

    $apartmentNumber = Report:: lists('apartment_number','id')->all();
    $commonArea = Report:: lists('common_area_name','id')->all();
    $createdDate = Report:: lists('created_date_time','id')->all();
    $status = Report:: lists('status','id')->all();
    $priority = Report:: lists('priority','id')->all();
    $assign = Report:: lists('assign_to','id')->all();
    $reportDatas=Report::all();

  return view('Report.index', compact('apartmentNumber','commonArea','createdDate','status','priority','assign','reportDatas','report'));
}

public function storeData(Request $request)
{
    $report = new Report();
    $report1 = $request->input();
    $report->id = trim($report1['apartment_number']);
    $aptNumber = Report::find($report->id)->apartment_number;
    $report->id = trim($report1['common_area_name']);
    $commonAreaName = Report::find($report->id)->common_area_name;
    $report->id = trim($report1['created_date_time']);
    $createdDateTime = Report::find($report->id)->created_date_time;
    $report->id = trim($report1['status']);
    $status1 = Report::find($report->id)->status;
    $report->id = trim($report1['priority']);
    $priority1 = Report::find($report->id)->priority;
    $report->id = trim($report1['assign']);
    $assign1 = Report::find($report->id)->assign_to;

    $apartmentNumber = Report:: lists('apartment_number','id')->all();
    $commonArea = Report:: lists('common_area_name','id')->all();
    $createdDate = Report:: lists('created_date_time','id')->all();
    $status = Report:: lists('status','id')->all();
    $priority = Report:: lists('priority','id')->all();
    $assign = Report:: lists('assign_to','id')->all();



    $reportDatas=Report::where('apartment_number', '=',$aptNumber)
       ->where('common_area_name', 'like' , $commonAreaName)
       ->where('created_date_time', '=' , $createdDateTime)
       ->where('status', 'like' , $status1)
       ->where('priority', 'like' , $priority1)
       ->where('assign_to', 'like' , $assign1)
       ->get();
    return view('Report.index', compact('apartmentNumber','commonArea','createdDate','status','priority','assign','reportDatas','report'));


}

}
```

Comment: You are getting `Trying to get property of non-object` at which line? It can be happen when you are accessing a property of an object which object doesn't exist.

Comment: share the error, I mean which line, Basically it will be in your `$reportDatas`. But any way check line and share it here !

Comment: You should check your MySQL query that it is not giving any error. Any of the variable defined might be an empty string
or it is not an object, and you are trying to access one of its properties. In such case, you can simply test by doing dd($variable), and check out the result.

Comment: I am getting error at  
       ->where('common_area_name', 'like' , $commonAreaName)

Comment: use dd($commonAreaName) and tell me what do you get, I think you are getting null value in that variable

Comment: Tried using dd($commanAreaName)  -                                                                            ErrorException in ReportController.php line 74:
Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: Add a check for not null. If it is not null then pass it to your view or controller (wherever desired). In this way, you wont have this problem